# Convert timestamp to slots. Python. Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Convert the above timestamp to the timeslots.

```
timestamp      Weather  Location
2014-10-26 00:00    35  1
2014-10-26 06:00    36  1
2014-10-26 12:00    34  1
2014-10-26 18:00    34  1
2014-10-27 00:00    35  1
2014-10-27 06:00    36  1
2014-10-27 12:00    36  1
2014-10-27 18:00    32  1
2014-10-28 00:00    35  1
2014-10-28 06:00    33  1
2014-10-28 12:00    35  1
2014-10-28 18:00    33  1
2014-10-26 00:00    45  2
2014-10-26 06:00    46  2
2014-10-26 12:00    41  2
2014-10-26 18:00    39  2
2014-10-27 00:00    46  2
2014-10-27 06:00    44  2
2014-10-27 12:00    45  2
2014-10-27 18:00    42  2
2014-10-28 00:00    41  2
2014-10-28 06:00    40  2
2014-10-28 12:00    42  2
2014-10-28 18:00    41  2
```

Each 6hrs timestamp is a slot.
The output i am expecting is :

```
timestamp      Weather  Location    Slot 
2014-10-26 00:00    35  1             1
2014-10-26 06:00    36  1             2
2014-10-26 12:00    34  1             3
2014-10-26 18:00    34  1             4
2014-10-27 00:00    35  1             1
2014-10-27 06:00    36  1             2
2014-10-27 12:00    36  1             3
2014-10-27 18:00    32  1             4
2014-10-28 00:00    35  1             1
2014-10-28 06:00    33  1             2
2014-10-28 12:00    35  1             3
2014-10-28 18:00    33  1             4
2014-10-26 00:00    45  2             1
2014-10-26 06:00    46  2             2
2014-10-26 12:00    41  2             3
2014-10-26 18:00    39  2             4
2014-10-27 00:00    46  2             1
2014-10-27 06:00    44  2             2
2014-10-27 12:00    45  2             3
2014-10-27 18:00    42  2             4
2014-10-28 00:00    41  2             1
2014-10-28 06:00    40  2             2
2014-10-28 12:00    42  2             3
2014-10-28 18:00    41  2             4
```

The slots must be divided to 6hrs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the [floor division](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/floor_division.html) of the hours by `6` and use the result as a custom grouper Then use [`GroupBy.ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) to obtain number for each group:

```
df.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)
df['slot'] = df.groupby(df.timestamp.dt.hour//6).ngroup()+1

timestamp  Weather  Location  slot
0  2014-10-26 00:00:00       35         1     1
1  2014-10-26 06:00:00       36         1     2
2  2014-10-26 12:00:00       34         1     3
3  2014-10-26 18:00:00       34         1     4
4  2014-10-27 00:00:00       35         1     1
5  2014-10-27 06:00:00       36         1     2
6  2014-10-27 12:00:00       36         1     3
7  2014-10-27 18:00:00       32         1     4
8  2014-10-28 00:00:00       35         1     1
9  2014-10-28 06:00:00       33         1     2
10 2014-10-28 12:00:00       35         1     3
11 2014-10-28 18:00:00       33         1     4
12 2014-10-26 00:00:00       45         2     1
13 2014-10-26 06:00:00       46         2     2
14 2014-10-26 12:00:00       41         2     3
...
```

Comment: What if each time slot is of 30 mins time slots

Comment: does this do what you want @Krush23? `df.groupby([df.timestamp.dt.hour, df.timestamp.dt.minute//30]).ngroup()+1`